# No roads on pokemon go

Tags: pokemon-go

I am using a galaxy S5. I have an error that I could only play the game on wifi (not on data). I tried numerous things to fix it including reseting app preferences as suggested by a user on this website. Now I still can't play the game on data plus no roads show up in my town (they still appeared before I reset app preferences) can anybody help me to get the game to work on data or at least to make it so I can see roads again?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this might help but since the app uses Google Maps, perhaps you can try to make the area where you live offline available?

Comment: This doesn't work -- pokemon go doesn't have access to any of google maps' data because the apps are sandboxed

Comment: Really? I read multiple articles that this way saves you a lot of battery life since there is no need to update realtime and it uses the offline map.

Comment: Check the date of those articles -- they should all be fairly old. This was a rumor that was spread around when the game first came out, but it's been disproven.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update! I'll be deleting them off my phone then now :-)